# Is there a RESTful way to cancel a GP Job?

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, rest

I have an asynchronous gp service that I can successfully run and cancel from within Arcmap.

Using fiddler I see that arcmap communicates with the GP service via SOAP.

I'd like to cancel the job using a REST request.  However I don't see anything in the documentation for the [GP Job](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/gpjob.html) describing how to do this.

Does anyone know if there's a RESTful way to cancel a job?

If not, would there be any bad side effects from writing another web service that scans the log file(s) to find the PID of the gp job then kills the process?  (The gp service is configured non-pooled).

**Update**
ESRI support confirmed no RESTful cancel method (incident #879881).  They suggested using the [SOAP cancelJob method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/soap/index.htm#SOAP_GP_CancelJob.htm) instead.

Comment: Enhance request has been submitted: #NIM063523 Provide a RESTful method to cancel GP jobs.

Comment: At 10.1 you can now cancel GP jobs through REST: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/gpCancel.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd be careful writing a sort of scanner/kill application thats available as a service (security concerns).
You could however keep it locally and just run it every X number of minutes using Task Scheduler. A Python script to read the log files, pull out the PID and then do a TASKKILL on the particular process would work.
However if you do that I'd suspect it would put your GP Service into a bad state and then you'd want to recycle that service.

How about just dropping down the "max time a client can use a service"? That may/may not do what you need depending on how "bad" a state your GP service is getting stuck into.

Comment: Thanks for responding Kevin.  I'm going to look into using SOAP for this.  If that doesn't work, I might look into a max time limit.  I suppose a timeout status is returned when that occurs(?)

Comment: I suggest having your GP jobs register themselves somehow (text file / DB table / etc) so that your kill script can only kill processes that have been registered.  Then you reduce the risk of someone finding it and exploiting it to shut other things down on your server.

Answer (score 2):

Though I realize the practical need, I don't think a "cancel job" request is ever a RESTful thing to do, i.e. cancelling a previous action implies state, but REST by definition is stateless.